# Appcenter build failed for android

Tags: android, azure, build, cicd, appcenter

I am running CI/CD from Appcenter for my Android Java project but failed with error code: 1.
below is the stacktrace

```
Build-tool 31.0.0 is missing DX at /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/dx

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeStagingAssets'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:stagingRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
      > Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew failed with return code: 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/1.128.0/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.js:569:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:351:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:509:12)
##[error]Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew failed with return code: 1
...
```

Comment: You can try this workaround to uninstall corrupted version 31.0.0 of Installed Build Tools revision: [Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9639)

Comment: Already tried this but no luck